# Starting installation from a small program

Tags: system-installation, iso

You can install openSUSE by booting from an USB pendrive being created by its Network image which is only 120MB, just point to where the installation image is on the local partition.

So most part of pendrive can be used for storing other datas.

This feature is useful to me, I want to know does it supported by other linux distros like MX Linux, Manjaro, Mageia?

Answer (score 0):

Some do. For example with Debian you can (or could) install using one or two floppy disks - everything else comes via network.  And Debian still has a `netinstall` disc offering - not quite as small but still "only" a few hundred MB.

Of course, if you want MORE space on your pen drive, you may want to look at DSL - well under 100mb for a full OS.

Comment: In the top 20 Linux distros listed in distrowatch.com, how many of them support the idea?